# XML: appendChild() with two loops? (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I have a problem... I want to know if the URL or TITLE in my XML file is containing some specified keywords. If yes, they should be added to the specified product. If no, a "Nothing" should be added to the specified product.

But my problem is that I don't have the knowledge to programm it so, that the program checks if the keywords from the array are in the URL or TITLE. Because if not the first keyword of the array is in the URL or TITLE it will always go into the else tribe and add "Nothing"...
How can I say that the progamm is only allowed to add "Nothing" if the program checked the 7 keywords in the `$searches` array?

Also the program must consider that the keyword values above 3 should be saved as "PlayStation" and not as "PS3", "PS4" or "PSN"!

And in addtion, how can I add them to my prodcuts? - I don't think that my code below is doing that...

Code:

```
$searches = ["Steam", "Uplay", "Xbox", "Nintendo", "PS3", "PS4", "PSN"];

function isContaining($searches, $titleTag, $urlTag, $productTag, $path){

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->load($path);
    $root = $dom->documentElement;

    $markerTitle = $root->getElementsByTagName($titleTag);
    $markerURL = $root->getElementsByTagName($urlTag);

    $plat = array();

    for($i = $markerTitle->length - 1; $i >= 0 ; $i--){

        $title = $markerTitle->item($i)->textContent;
        $url = $markerURL->item($i)->textContent;

        $co = count($searches);

        for($j = 0; $j < $co; $j++){
            if(stripos($title, $searches[$j]) !== false){
                if($j > 4){
                    array_push($plat, "PlayStation");
                }elseif($j < 5){
                    array_push($plat, $searches[$j]);
                }
            }elseif(stripos($url, $searches[$j]) !== false){
                if($j > 4){
                    array_push($plat, "PlayStation");
                }elseif($j < 5){
                    array_push($plat, $searches[$j]);
                }
            }elseif($j == 7 && stripos($url, $searches[$j]) == false){
                array_push($plat, "Nothing");
            }
        }
    }

    array_reverse($plat);
    print_r($plat);
    $c = count($plat);

    for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++){
        $node = $dom->createElement('plat', $plat[$c]);
        $dom->getElementsByTagName($productTag)->item($i)->appendChild($node);
    }


    $dom->saveXML();
    $dom->save($path);
}

isContaining($searches, "name", "link", "product", $gamesplanetPath);
```

Greetings and Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace your inner for loop with this following code:

```
$productFound = false;
for($j = 0; $j < $co; $j++){
    if(stripos($title, $searches[$j]) !== false){
        if($j > 3){
            array_push($plat, "PlayStation");
        }else{
            array_push($plat, $searches[$j]);
        }
        $productFound = true;
    }elseif(stripos($url, $searches[$j]) !== false){
        if($j > 3){
            array_push($plat, "PlayStation");
        }else{
            array_push($plat, $searches[$j]);
        }
        $productFound = true;
    }
}
if($productFound == false){
    array_push($plat, "Nothing");
}
```

NOTE: the array index start from 0

Regarding your last question

> how can I add them to my prodcuts?

I don't know what you mean by adding to your product.

Comment: Thanks, your code helps me! - But now I want to add the values in my array to the specified product. You know what I mean?

I want to create a new Element with DOMDocument and append the values from the array to the specified products. So a new attribute. How can I do that...

The problem is that my Code is telling me that the array with the values isn't as long as the product list. But that can't be! 
We save every value or say nothing!

Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Jan, the array may be longer than your product list. In case of one URL contains more than one key word, for example it contains both 'steam' and 'xbox', the array will be added twice.